# Access WindowedApplication from package class

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I'm developing an AIR application, where i need to access
WindowedApplication's function from the package class.

This is the Main application (Partial code)

```
<mx:WindowedApplication  xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="absolute" creationComplete="initApplication()">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

 import mx.events.CloseEvent;
 import messages.MessageWindow
public function undock():void {

        stage.nativeWindow.visible = true;
        stage.nativeWindow.orderToFront();

        //Clearing the bitmaps array also clears the applcation icon from the systray

        NativeApplication.nativeApplication .icon.bitmaps = [];
    }

  ]]>
</mx:Script>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Package: (Partial code)

---

```
package messages
{
  public class MessageWindow extends NativeWindow
  {

    public function MessageWindow():void
    {

     stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onClick);

    }
    private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        ****** Need to call the undock method from here. *****

    }
  }

}
```

Is it possible to call this way or suggest any other solution

Thanks in advance
Senling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if I don't recommend this for the sake of your code design, you can access your method like this:
Application.application.undock()
(if your undock() method is public in the WindowedApplication )

Answer (score 1):

Cant see why it shouldnt work. Go ahead and give it a try, and if any errors come up, post it here.

What you can maybe try is to add parentApplication in front of stage in the MessageWindow method, like this..

```
parentApplication.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onClick);
```

and then call the undock() method from the onClick() method

Comment: have you tried adding parentApplication to the undock() method?

Comment: in the onClick() method, use parentApplication.undock() instead of just undock()

Comment: Hi, pietervn, thanks for your fast response.
I couldn't access the parentApplication property from message.MessageWindow. i also tried mx.core.UIComponent.parentApplication. 
I'm trying to dispatch event from message.MessageWindow class to main WindowedApplication which listens that event to call the undock method., but it failed.